# Display some text when binded listview has no items

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listview

Following is the syntax for my listview which is binded to a class....

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewStyle}" Name="transactionListView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseDoubleClick="transactionListView_MouseDoubleClick" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource gridViewHeaderColumnStyle}">
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Serial" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Serial}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Seller" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Seller}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Buyer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Buyer}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Bales" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bales}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

*How can i display some text when the list is empty or contain no items?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The trick is in overriding ListView's template. When there are no items in ListView you should set your ControlTemplate with TextBlock:

```
<ListView Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                         Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                                <TextBlock Text="No items..."/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```

Comment: There is just one small problem...it hides the gridviewcolumns header....anyways i will look into this and try to make sure that this style can be applied to listviewitem and not the listview itself...

Comment: The first thing has come in mind - duplicate listview declaration (without ItemsSource, but with ListView.View) before TextBlock to ControlTemplate (you should wrap them with StackPanel, for exapmle).

Comment: Just to note that this works equally well with ItemsControls other than ListBox, with very few modifications.

Answer (score 2):

The ListView itself does not supply this functionality. The simplest approach is to place a TextBlock in front of the ListView with its Visibility set to Collapsed. You can then make it Visible when your list has no items in it.

If you need help with the specific, please expand your question.

Comment: I guess this is the way to do it, but i am not able to understand as to where should i insert the texblock in above code and how to achieve this.