# WPF listbox empty item template not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am try to list some data in WPF listbox control. It is the first time I am using DataTemplate in WPF. Everything is working fine except when there is no data it is not showing 'No items to display'. Below is my code.

```
    <ListBox Name="itemsCtrl" Background="#FFE5E5E5" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="itemsCtrl_SelectionChanged" Style="{StaticResource ListStyle}">

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <!-- Set SelectedItem Background here -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#C2C2C2"/>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                      Self}}"
                        Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                         Value="#C2C2C2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="ListStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Items.Count}" 
    Value="0"
    >
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock>No items to display</TextBlock>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Resources>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Cursor="Hand" Name="hoverDataTemplate" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="370" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="15,5,5,5" Width="330"  Content="{Binding Path=EVENT_TITLE}" FontSize="12"/>
                    <Image Height="28" Source="/pr;component/Images/black_next.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="28" />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And I am binding data source as shown below.

```
    itemsCtrl.ItemsSource = dao.SelectDataTable(cmd).DefaultView;
```

When I set the style property of ListBox as ListStyle it is throwing an error

```
'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '292' and line position '22'.
```

Can anybody point out how to make it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you've defined ListStyle but you didn't set ListBox's style to it.

Comment: @Bizz thanks for the comment. I missed to post that line here. I have updated my question. Setting liststyle also is not working.

Comment: if "Items" is null, then Items.Count won't be equal to 0. make sure you instantiate Items before anything.

Comment: I checked item is not null. but its throwing an error while setting listbox style. 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '292' and line position '22'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display some text when binded listview has no items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918383/display-some-text-when-binded-listview-has-no-items)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have used below code and it's work fine 
my xaml code

```
<ListBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,2,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource Dhaval}"/>
```

Style look like

```
<Style x:Key="Dhaval" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>No items to display</TextBlock>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: have u checked your listbox should have no value when u want to show no items to display textblock? because it's work fine if your listbox should have no value. i chekced it proper.

Comment: it is showing an error 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '292' and line position '22'. when I set listbox style.

Comment: set the style in App.xaml file and then give StaticResource. i think it should work now.